# How to spool each row in a different file at oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, loops, spool

I have a table with a few columns, one of them is a LOB.
What i need to do is create a XML file for each row in the table.

As the spool does not work inside a loop, i wonder if there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: How many rows are your dealing with?

Comment: Have you considered writing all rows into a single xml file and postprocess this file with suitable tool ( eg. a xslt processor or a tool like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)  )?

Comment: 100000 rows. I really need them in separated files..

Answer (score 0):

you need open cursor and use dbms_lob package to save each your lob value to drive.

```
begin
  for rc in (select * from my_table) loop
    my_save_lob_function(rc.lob, rc.file_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

here you can find the functions that save LOB to file
http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_10.shtml

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the my_save_lob_function, can you help me with that part?

Comment: you need replace the `my_save_lob_function` by function `Write_BLOB_To_File` from link below. the `Write_BLOB_To_File` function from the link is bit complex and I didn't add it to the comment